# integration help for calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_1^3(8x+12)e^{x^2 + 3x - 5}\,dx$$

$$u = x^2 + 3x - 5\implies du = 2x+3$$

$$\int_1^3(8x+12)e^{x^2 + 3x - 5}\,dx = 4\int (2x+3)e^{x^2 + 3x - 5}\,dx$$

$$= 4\int e^u\,du = 4e^u + c = 4e^{x^2 + 3x - 5}\Big|_1^3$$

This is what I have done so far, at the moment I am currently lost and do not know what to do next or even if my current work is correct.

Comment: just put the limits in then its good to go.. $$\left[f(u)\right]_{a}^{b} = f(b) - f(a)$$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done is perfectly fine. You found the indefinite integral $F(x)= 4e^{\large(x^2+3x -5)}$.

Now, you need only evaluate the definite integral at the given bounds, from $x = 1$ to $x=3$:

$$4e^{\large(x^2+3x -5)}\Big|_1^3 = F(3) - F(1) = 4e^{\large( (3)^2 + 3(3) - 5)}- 4e^{\large((1)^2 + 3(1) - 5)}$$

Comment: is the answer 1.471?

Comment: $$4e^{13} - 4e^{-1} = 4e^{-1}(e^{14} - 1) = \dfrac{4(e^{14}-1)}{e}$$ That's a very large number.

Comment: Now I see where I made my mistake, I didn't carry the negative sign. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: would the exponent by 4e^12 instead of 4e^14?

Comment: You're welcome, Ben.

Comment: $\dfrac{e^{14}}{e} = e^{13}$ Note that $4e^{-1}\cdot e^{14} = 4\cdot e^{14 + (- 1)} = 4e^{13}$